# Reordering a heatmap for maximal contrast between subgroups

Tags: r, heatmap

I've created a heatmap using `aheatmap` from NMF package:

```
aheatmap(x, scale="row", 
         color = "heat",
         annColors = "Set2", 
         annCol=annotation, 
         Colv = NA, 
         Rowv = "man", 
         main = "All patients")
```

So I get the following result:

[image]

However, the heatmap does not really show what I intended... I want to have "lots of yellow", when the therapy group is high and "lots of red" when the therapy group is low. Is there any way to reorder the rows/columns, so that I can make the best out of the data? Should I perhaps use another heatmap package?

Comment: But the heatmap just shows your data as it is. Do you actually have higher values in the 'high' therapy group? You could try adjusting the colour palette to `'rainbow'` to see whether that gives a bit more contrast, but it may just be that your data don't show what you hope they would show.

Comment: log fold changes in gene expression are usually best expressed with a diverging color palette, that centers on a neutral color at 0. See the [Brewer](https://colorbrewer2.org/#type=diverging&scheme=PRGn&n=3) scales for options/inspiration.